# stop loss feature isn't working in pine editor

Tags: trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, pine-script-v4

neither one of these stop losses are working, one is fixed dollar amount and the other is a percentage based on overall account value, could please get help:

```
loss_threshold = input(-50, title="Loss Threshold")
percent_loss_threshold = input(0.3, title="Percent Loss Threshold (%)")

// Calculate percent loss
account_balance = strategy.equity
percent_loss = (unrealized_pnl / account_balance) * 100

/ Define auto close condition for percent loss
`if percent_loss <= -percent_loss_threshold
strategy.close("Long")
strategy.close("Short")
```